# Android boolean if not condition not working

Tags: android

I have check against a boolean value if(!updating_questions) that is not working in my intent service in the following method

```
private void sendBroadcast(Context context, String key, String value){
    //Don't broadcast if updating questions
    Util.log_debug_message("@@@@ Updating questions - " + updating_questions);
    if(!updating_questions){
        Util.log_debug_message("@@@@ Broadcasting, updating_questions = " + updating_questions);
        Broadcast.sendBroadcast(context, ResponseReceiver.ACTION_RESP, Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT,
                key, value);
    }
}
```

The updating_questions flag is a global private variable and it's value is false

```
private boolean updating_questions = false;
```

The value is set from an extra in the onHandleIntent(Intent intent) method

```
    updating_questions = intent.getBooleanExtra(AppConstants.C2DM_MESSAGE_UPDATE_QUESTIONS, false);
```

The value is set using

```
    if(updating_questions){
        refreshService.putExtra(AppConstants.C2DM_MESSAGE_UPDATE_QUESTIONS, true);
    } else {
        refreshService.putExtra(AppConstants.C2DM_MESSAGE_UPDATE_QUESTIONS, false);
    }
```

This check seems to be behaing itslef properly
and the output in the console shows that the value is false but the condition is being treated as if it true

```
D/QuizApp (  878): @@@@ Updating questions - false
D/QuizApp (  878): @@@@ Broadcasting, updating_questions = false
```

So if the value is false how is it possible to be broadcasting the message?
I'm obviously missing something really fundamental but haven't a clue what it is

Comment: That set statement is redundant; just set the app constant to the value of updating_questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `if` condition is:

```
!updating_questions
```

This means that *do this block* if `updating_questions` is **NOT** `true`(see the `!` operator).

Comment: Thank you for the reply, So how do I prevent the block from being called if updating_questions is false?

Comment: @jamesw Remove the `!` from the `if` condition: `if(updating_questions){ //...` .

Comment: @jamesw Uh... You want it to execute if the value is true, but you don't?

Comment: ok, I think I have the problem sorted! Just a flaw in my logic. Sorry

Comment: A quick follow up. My condition is correct it's just that the value was being set to false when it should have been set to true. Need more coffee!

Comment: As good practice, and as an aid to maintaining sanity, avoid "negative logic checks" whenever possible.  Makes no difference to how your code runs, but makes a huge difference to reading, understanding and maintaining.  if (condition){} is much better than if (!condition){}. Boolean field names that begin "not", e.g. notUpdated are giveaways to negative logic "code smells".

Comment: An even better lesson. Don't expect your code to work the way you expected when you have had no sleep for 24 hours :)